# How to redirect visitors to country-specific URLs based on their geolocations?

Tags: apache, web, servlets

My question is that how to serve webpage according to country. For example when we enter www.google.com in address bar of browser it opens www.google.co.in if you are from India instead of www.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

https://torbjornzetterlund.com/how-to-configure-htaccess-redirects-based-on-geo-ip/

Here is good blog for your question.
The concept behind this is first get ip region and set redirection rule in .htaccess file.

Comment: I am new to learning Apache. So I have question related to code. That is "is it applicable only for php or any language such as html, JavaScript? "